# GitHub issues as separate repo?

Tags: github

There's already an [API for GitHub issues](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/), but has anyone succeeded in making it two-way? That is:

```
git clone git@github.com:user/repo.issues.git # Like for wiki
editor repo.issues/1.json
git push -u origin master
```

And voilà, a new/updated issue #1!

It could use a pre-receive hook to validate before accepting any pushes, so invalid formatting shouldn't be a problem.

In other words, **is there some way to handle the issues of a GitHub project as another GitHub repo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using the API, I don't see how this can be done *cleanly*.

You *could* put together a (custom) monstrosity that updates a separate GitHub repo with all the *issues* in said repo at a predefined interval (using the API), but given the effort involved, this better be worth it to you :)